# How to display data in React select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a filter for movies based on their categories using React select when I displed my data (Categories inside the Select) it didn't work. I've tried a lot but still not working.

I'm a newbie in React so thank you for any help or comments.

- "categories" are variables from the state where I stored all the - categories
  -["Comedy", "Animation", "Thriller", "Drame"]

-FilterMovie is a function to filter the movie based on its category

ps: Movies are stored in a separate state

This is CategoriesFilter :

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';


const CategoriesFilter = ({categories, filterMovie}) => {
    return (
    <div>  
    
    <Select
    className="select-option"
    options={categories}
    placeholder={"type something"}
    />
    </div>
      
    )
}

export default CategoriesFilter;
```

Filter movies came from app.js

```
 //filter movies based on their categories
  const filterMovie = (category) => {
    const filterMovie = MoviesData.filter((movie)=> movie.category === category);
    setMoviesList(filterMovie);
  }
```

Comment: What does the `filterMovie` function look like? Also, where is the `Select` component from, is it from a component library?

Comment: Please check out the updated code, i just edited :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `react-select` API requires the `options` to be formatted as an array of objects with `value` and `label` keys. You can do this using a Array.map method. Then, you can pass your `filterMovie` function directly to the `onChange` handler of the component.

```
const CategoriesFilter = ({ categories, filterMovie }) => {
  const options = cateogries.map((c) => ({ value: c, label: c }));

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        className="select-option"
        options={options}
        placeholder={"type something"}
        onChange={filterMovie}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Nick :D , it works and I just learned something so interesting from you about react select,  but when I click on a value, the filter doesn't work, it deleted all my list ?

Comment: It's possible that `movie.category === category`  is always false. What does `movie.category` look like?

Comment: movie.category is represented each category for each movie from this state (MoviesData) is an array of objects with id , title ,category ... const [moviesList, setMoviesList] = useState(MoviesData);